# Questions about Hinnant's stack allocator

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-alignment, allocator, exception-specification

I've been using Howard Hinnant's [stack allocator](http://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.h) and it works like a charm, but some details of the implementation are a little unclear to me.

1. Why are global operators `new` and `delete` used? The `allocate()` and `deallocate()` member functions use `::operator new` and `::operator delete` respectively. Similarly, the member function `construct()` uses the global placement new. Why not allow for any user-defined global or class-specific overloads?
2. Why is alignment set to hard-coded 16 bytes instead of `std::alignment_of<T>`?
3. Why do the constructors and `max_size` have a `throw()` exception specification? Isn't this discouraged (see e.g. More Effective C++ Item 14.)? Is it really necessary to terminate and abort when an exception occurs in the allocator? Does this change with the new C++11 `noexcept` keyword?
4. The `construct()` member function would be an ideal candidate for perfect forwarding (to the constructor that is being called). Is this the way to write C++11 conformant allocators?
5. What other changes are necessary to make the current code C++11 conformant?

Comment: `::new (p) T` guarantees you that you will construct a `T` and nothing else will happen. If a class wants to provide an allocation function that has the same signature as the usual global placement new, then presumably it does something more. Think of `::new (p) T` as an explicit constructor call, not as memory allocation (the latter of which makes sense to override. (Note that's it's not possible to override the usual global placement new.)

Comment: @LucDanton OK, so if a class has defined its own placement new (e.g. for logging purposes), this will still be called by `::new(p) T`?

Comment: @rhalbersma if you want to log that kind of thing, log in the constructor. That placement `new` is (unlike other forms of `new`) a primitive of the language, and that's why overriding it is very sketchy.

Comment: No. And that class should just as well log in the constructor. The point of `void* operator new(std::size_t, void*);` is that it's a no-op.

Comment: For the alignment at least, Effective C++ (3rd Ed.) says (Item 50, p. 249) : "C++ requires that all `operator new`s return pointers that are suitably aligned for *any* data type. `malloc` labors under the same requirement." This usually means 16-byte aligned, so he is being consistent with that. Don't know if c11 and c++11 are the same, but it's likely.

Comment: @BoBTFish If I have a struct that is precisely one cacheline (64-bytes) long, how do I align a the data of a `std::vector` of such structs then to a 64-byte boundary?

Comment: @rhalbersma That `struct` can be safely aligned at a smaller boundary. However, if you want to *force* it at a 64-byte boundary, you'll have to do it yourself, but I can't say I know much about this. C++11 has some facilities for this.

Comment: To complement BoBTFish's comment, there's `alignas` for declaring aligned members, `std::aligned_storage` for aligned automatic raw storage, and `std::align` for aligned dynamically allocated raw storage.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> I've been using Howard Hinnant's [stack allocator](http://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.h) and it works
>   like a charm, but some details of the implementation are a little
>   unclear to me.

Glad it's been working for you.

> 1. Why are global operators `new` and `delete` used? The `allocate()` and `deallocate()` member functions use `::operator new` and
>   `::operator delete` respectively. Similarly, the member function
>   `construct()` uses the global placement new. Why not allow for any
>   user-defined global or class-specific overloads?

There's no particular reason.  Feel free to modify this code in whatever way works best for you.  This was meant to be more of an example, and it is by no means perfect.  The only requirements are that the allocator and deallocator supply properly aligned memory, and that the construct member constructs an argument.

In C++11, the construct (and destroy) members are optional.  I would encourage you to remove them from the allocator if you're operating in an environment that supplies `allocator_traits`.  To find out, just remove them and see if things still compile.

> 2. Why is alignment set to hard-coded 16 bytes instead of `std::alignment_of<T>`?

`std::alignment_of<T>` would probably work fine.  I was probably being paranoid that day.

> 3. Why do the constructors and `max_size` have a `throw()` exception specification? Isn't this discouraged (see e.g. More Effective C++
>   Item 14.)? Is it really necessary to terminate and abort when an
>   exception occurs in the allocator? Does this change with the new C++11
>   `noexcept` keyword?

These members just won't ever throw.  For C++11 I should update them to `noexcept`.  In C++11 it becomes more important to decorate things with `noexcept`, especially special members.  In C++11 one can detect whether an expression is nothrow or not.  Code can branch depending on that answer.  Code that is known to be nothrow is more likely to cause generic code to branch to a more efficient path.  `std::move_if_noexcept` is the canonical example in C++11.

Don't use `throw(type1, type2)` ever.  It has been deprecated in C++11.

Do use `throw()` when you really want to say:  This will never throw, and if I'm wrong, terminate the program so I can debug it.  `throw()` is also deprecated in C++11, but has a drop-in replacement: `noexcept`.

> 4. The `construct()` member function would be an ideal candidate for perfect forwarding (to the constructor that is being called). Is this
>   the way to write C++11 conformant allocators?

Yes.  However `allocator_traits` will do it for you.  Let it.  The std::lib has already debugged that code for you.  C++11 containers will call `allocator_traits<YourAllocator>::construct(your_allocator, pointer, args...)`.  If your allocator implements these functions, allocator_traits will call your implementation, else it calls a debugged, efficient, default implementation.

> 5. What other changes are necessary to make the current code C++11 conformant?

To tell you the truth, this allocator isn't really C++03 or C++11 conformant.  When you copy an allocator, the original and the copy are supposed to be equal to each other.  In this design, that is never true.  However this thing still just happens to work in many contexts.

If you want to make it strictly conforming, you need another level of indirection such that copies will point to the same buffer.

Aside from that, C++11 allocators are *so* much easier to build than C++98/03 allocators.  Here's the minimum you must do:

```
template <class T>
class MyAllocator
{
public:
    typedef T value_type;

    MyAllocator() noexcept;  // only required if used
    MyAllocator(const MyAllocator&) noexcept;  // copies must be equal
    MyAllocator(MyAllocator&&) noexcept;  // not needed if copy ctor is good enough
    template <class U>
        MyAllocator(const MyAllocator<U>& u) noexcept;  // requires: *this == MyAllocator(u)

    value_type* allocate(std::size_t);
    void deallocate(value_type*, std::size_t) noexcept;
};

template <class T, class U>
bool operator==(const MyAllocator<T>&, const MyAllocator<U>&) noexcept;

template <class T, class U>
bool operator!=(const MyAllocator<T>&, const MyAllocator<U>&) noexcept;
```

You might optionally consider making `MyAllocator` Swappable and put the following nested type in the allocator:

```
typedef std::true_type propagate_on_container_swap;
```

There's a few other knobs like that you can tweak on C++11 allocators.  But all of the knobs have reasonable defaults.

**Update**

Above I note that my [stack allocator](http://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.h) is not conforming due to the fact that copies are not equal.  I've decided to update this allocator to a conforming C++11 allocator.  The new allocator is called [short_allocator](http://howardhinnant.github.io/short_alloc.h) and is documented [here](http://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.html).

The [short_allocator](http://howardhinnant.github.io/short_alloc.h) differs from the [stack allocator](http://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.h) in that the "internal" buffer is no longer internal to the allocator, but is now a separate "arena" object that can be located on the local stack, or given thread or static storage duration.  The `arena` isn't thread safe though so watch out for that. You could make it thread safe if you wanted to, but that has diminishing returns (eventually you'll reinvent malloc).

This is conforming because copies of allocators all point to the same external `arena`.  Note that the unit of `N` is now bytes, not number of `T`.

One could convert this C++11 allocator to a C++98/03 allocator by adding the C++98/03 boiler-plate (the typedefs, the construct member, the destroy member, etc.).  A tedious, but straightforward task.

The answers to this question for the new [short_allocator](http://howardhinnant.github.io/short_alloc.h) remain unchanged.

Comment: Your original code works on VC++ with the following modifications: disable warning 4100 (it thinks that `p` is unreferenced in `p->~T()`), and some reshuffling of pointer arithmetic: instead of `(pointer)&buf_ + N - ptr_ >= n`, I had to write `ptr_ + n <= (pointer)&buf_ + N` to avoid spurious signed/unsigned errors.

Comment: VC++ does not have `<allocator_traits>`, and I have manually written a few overloads for construct. I also wrote `pointer begin() { return reinterpret_cast<pointer> &buf_; }` to emphasize the pointer conversion, and `pointer end() { return begin() + N; }` for convenience.

Comment: Perhaps an interesting performance stat: I use `stack_alloc` in a checkers/draughts game engine that generates around 1 million move lists per second, where a move is a 24-byte struct, and I use `N=32` for the allocator. The speed is more or less identical to the combo `std::allocator` and `vector.reserve(32)`, but without the hassle of having to write this everywhere (or of having to write a container wrapper that does this). Performance is within 12% of `std::array`, but without the safety concern. See this thread on a computer chess forum: http://talkchess.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=39934

Comment: @rhalbersma : That thread is really only interesting if one enjoys the ramblings of a C++ hater. :-P

Comment: @HowardHinnant One more Microsoft specific wart: in Debug mode, the code compiles but at runtime it will hit asserts emitted by the iterator debugging macro `_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)` in the `operator delete`.

Comment: @HowardHinnant, std::maxalign_t is not defined in all libraries. Instead of setting it to 16 I have found following suggestion howto compute it: http://t5721.codeinpro.us/q/515022e3e8432c042620e111. If memory space is really scarce, it is possible to do a per case calculation using bitwise operations and the alignof operator as in the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752546/how-does-malloc-understand-alignment/18479609#18479609 I wonder why placement new does not do it automatically. Maybe because unaligned mem is legal for some compilers and only results in slower code?

Comment: @HowardHinnant, I just see that you only align the memory buffer but not the objects in the buffer (i.e. only the first object in the buffer is well aligned). I thought the objects themselves must be well aligned but the buffer does not matter. Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781724/do-i-really-have-to-worry-about-alignment-when-using-placement-new-operator

Comment: @HowardHinnant, the links to the allocator don't seem to function any longer. Has the code been uploaded somewhere else?

Comment: @HowardHinnant, is there something like this in boost or the standard library? If not, are there plans for that?

Comment: Boost has some allocators.  I'm not familiar with them.  Just search for "allocator" in the boost docs.  Currently the only allocator in the standard is `std::allocator`.  Here http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3525.pdf is a proposal to add more.

Comment: Isn't `pointer_in_buffer´ exhibiting undefined behavior if the pointer doesn't point into the buffer? I think you can't compare pointers to objects that are not part of the same array or struct with the relational operators `<,>,<=,>=`. It is explicitly UB in C, but in c++  standard, there just seems to be no mention of what should happen in this case. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766570/how-do-i-safely-and-sensibly-determine-whether-a-pointer-points-somewhere-into-a)

Comment: @MikeMB:  Yes.  This is the sort of thing that is UB because 6 guys in a dark room said so a few decades ago.  If they had said something else, it would be something else.  The reason they said so is because at the time segmented architectures were a clear and present danger.  My code above assumes a flat address space, and a compiler that won't arbitrarily change your code based on that outdated decision from decades ago (which is an increasingly dangerous assumption as compiler optimizers move ever further into the too-clever-by-half arena).

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @MikeMB Using N4527, [expr.rel]/4 leaves unrelated pointer comparisons *unspecified* (see [defns.unspecified]), not *undefined* (see  [defns.undefined]). The easy fix for `pointer_in_buffer` is to use `std::less_equal` for which it is specified that "For templates `greater`, `less`, `greater_equal`, and `less_equal`, the specializations for any pointer type yield a total order, even if the built-in operators <, >, <=, >= do not." (see [comparisons]/14). Looking at the libc++ and libstdc++ sources, there don't appear to be any specializations for pointer comparisons in `<functional>`, though.

Comment: @TemplateRex:  The reason there aren't any specializations in libc++ and libstdc++ is because std::libs are allowed to write non-portable code so that the clients of the std::libs don't have to.  And libc++ and libstdc++ have chosen not to target platforms where such specializations would have different syntax than the primary template.

Comment: @TemplateRex: Thank you very much, I've read [expr.rel] multiple times and always read over that passage.

Comment: 0

@HowardHinnant vector.reserve() with the related stack size must be called on the vector, before pushing something to the vector. Else, the "grow" (realloc) method of the vector, will consume the stack space unnecessarily. At least this is what I could observe with Visual Studio 2017 implementation of std::vector.

Comment: More up-to-date post on this allocator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34211227/576911