# How to compile Hinnant's short_alloc allocator

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

I'd like to try the new [Hinnant's short_alloc allocator](http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/stack_alloc.html) that, as far as I can understand, replaces the old [stack_alloc](http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/stack_alloc.h) allocator. However, I can't manage to compile the vector example. `g++` says:

```
~# g++ -std=c++11 stack-allocator-test.cpp -o stack-allocator-test
In file included from stack-allocator-test.cpp:6:0:
short_alloc.h:11:13: error: ‘alignment’ is not a type
short_alloc.h:11:22: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘alignas’ with no type [-fpermissive]
short_alloc.h:11:22: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
```

As far as I can tell, `g++` complains about `line 10` and `11`:

```
static const std::size_t alignment = 16;
alignas(alignment) char buf_[N];
```

It seems that the compiler doesn't like the "expression version" of [alignas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) but it expects just the "type-id version".

I'm using `g++ 4.7.2` under Ubuntu 12.10.

```
~# g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2
```

Probably I'm missing something obvious, but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated. (Please don't tell me I have to upgrade to a newer `g++`, I'm too lazy to do that :)

Comment: Yes, I thought the same, but `std::size_t` should be defined because `<cstddef>` is correctly included. And if it were `std::size_t`'s fault, the first error would be at `line 10`...

Comment: I'm also looking at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11652436/1396334) to have some more clue. No luck till now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

g++-4.7.2 doesn't support `alignas`.  From http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html:

> Alignment support |   N2341 | GCC 4.8

Try using g++-4.8.0 or clang; alternatively you may be able to use the [`__attribute__((aligned))`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#Variable%20Attributes):

```
__attribute__((aligned (8))) char buf_[12];
```

Note that `__attribute__((aligned))` only accepts certain integer constant expressions (literals, template parameters); it doesn't accept `static const` variables.

Comment: Ok, I suspected that. Thank you for the link.

Comment: You are right. With `__attribute__((aligned (8)))` it compiles without errors. Thank you again.