# Stack allocator for C++03 standard containers

Tags: c++, stl, c++03, allocator

For a software I have to avoid any use of memory in the heap, and only rely on stack-allocated memory.  Then, this prevents me from using any C++ standard containers, such as vector, map, string (well, basic_string), which I would really like to use, to ease development and data manipulation.

I found (many) implementations of stack allocators, such as [this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31528/a-working-stack-allocator) which itself references two others, or [this one](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/base/containers/stack_container.h) from chromium.

Many of them are not fully compliant with the standard, or rely on C++11 (and I am stuck with C++03 at the moment, sadly). Do you have any feedback about a good already existing stack allocator for C++03 or should I adapt one of the above?

Thanks!

Comment: Howard Hinnant gives a [C++03 bolierplate for his allocator](http://howardhinnant.github.io/allocator_boilerplate.html) also see [Questions about Hinnant's stack allocator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11648202/1708801)

Answer (score 4):

Howard Hinnant's [short_alloc.h](http://howardhinnant.github.io/short_alloc.h) ([see also here](http://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.html)) is a pretty good start (you will need to add C++03 boilerplate, see [here](http://howardhinnant.github.io/allocator_boilerplate.html)).

Of course, this will still go to the heap if it runs out of memory, the alternative is to throw `std::bad_alloc`.